# OnCheckedChange Event does not execute my event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, autopostback, oncheckedchanged

I've been reading a few posts in here and some are related to my problem, but for some reason the solutions provided dont work for me. Basically I have two GridView controls with checkboxes. They have the exact same code, but just fire different events. And of course have different IDs and their pertinent unique information. Here is the weird thing, one of them works just fine, and the other one doesn't. I will post both here, keep in mind that the one with ID="UnassignElegibilityChk" is the onte that is not working. I've put breakpoints to test whether I am inside the function when I send the postback from the check and nothing.

Note: both of these treeviews are on the same page, so please assume the codebehind directive and all the settings are properly assigned to the page (since one of them is working i would assume there is no problem with that)

This is the one that is not working:

```
   <table><tr><td class="style1">
    <asp:GridView ID="ElegibilitySelectedGridview" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="475px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID0" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="UnassignElegibilityChk" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="UnAssignElegibilityRecord"/>
            </ItemTemplate>                   
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="Name"  HeaderText="Elegible Item" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    </td></tr></table>
```

The one that is working is below:

```
<table><tr><td class="style1">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ElegibilityGroupDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ElegibilityGroupDDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">ROOT</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</td></tr><tr><td class="style1">
    <asp:TextBox ID="ElegibilityNameTxt" runat="server" Width="464px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td></tr><tr><td class="style1">
    <asp:Button ID="ElegibilitySaveBtn" runat="server" Text="Save Elegibility" />
    &nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class="style1">
    <asp:Label ID="ElegibilityMsgLbl" runat="server" Text="" style="color: #0066CC"></asp:Label>
    </td></tr><tr style="background:silver"><td class="style1">
    &nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class="style1">

    <asp:GridView ID="ElegibilityGridView" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="95%">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="AssignElegibilityChk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="AssignElegibility"/>
            </ItemTemplate>                   
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="Name"  HeaderText="Elegible Item" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
    </asp:GridView>
    </td></tr></table>
```

The working gridview fires this function successfully:

```
 Public Sub AssignElegibility()
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        For Each row As GridViewRow In ElegibilityGridView.Rows
            Dim checkbox As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("AssignElegibilityChk"), CheckBox)
            'Check if the checkbox is checked.'
            'value in the HtmlInputCheckBox Value property is set as the //value of the delete commands parameter.'
            If checkbox.Checked Then
                ' Retreive the Employee ID'
                Dim lblID As Label = CType(row.FindControl("lblID"), Label)
                Dim elegibilityID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text)
                Elegibility.AddElegibilityMapping(CInt(Request("ResID")), elegibilityID)
                ElegibilitySelectedItems(CInt(Request("ResID")))
                ElegibilityGroupDDL_SelectedIndexChanged()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The non working one is supposed to fire this code and it isn't.

```
Public Sub UnAssignElegibilityRecord(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    PrintLine("Inside the sub")
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        For Each row As GridViewRow In ElegibilitySelectedGridview.Rows
            Dim checkbox As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("UnassignElegibilityChk"), CheckBox)
            'Check if the checkbox is checked.'
            'value in the HtmlInputCheckBox Value property is set as the //value of the delete commands parameter.'
            If checkbox.Checked Then
                ' Retreive the Employee ID'
                Dim lblID As Label = CType(row.FindControl("lblID0"), Label)
                Dim elegibilityID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text)
                Elegibility.RemoveElegibilityMapping(elegibilityID)
                ElegibilitySelectedItems(CInt(Request("ResID")))
                ElegibilityGroupDDL_SelectedIndexChanged()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jovanky - adding "Help please" isn't going to make people answer you any faster.

Comment: My friend, some things come as a second nature. Dont pay attention to such minutia please. Life is a lot simpler. Enjoy your day!

Comment: You don't have two treeviews but two gridviews.

Comment: It seems odd that the method you say is working doesn't take any arguments, but the one that isn't working does (`sender As Object, e As EventArgs`). Are these definitely the right way round, and have you got `AutoEventWireup="True"` in your Page declaration?

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the correction (Edited), 
@Graham, AutoEventWireup is false on my page (and yet one GridView is working fine). And as far as the sender As Object, e As EventArgs on the non-working event, that was just an attempt to get it to fire but nothing is happening, it isnt even trying to call the event.

Comment: When you "View Source" do you see an onclick event for UnassignElegibilityChk?  There should be one there that calls __doPostBack().  That's how AutoPostBack works.  If it's not there that explains the event not firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if anything of the following solves your problem, but ...

1. why does your "working" handler of the CheckedChanged has the wrong signature? It needs the sender and the eventsargs.

   `protected Sub AssignElegibility(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)`
2. Why do you iterate the Gridrows to get the Checkbox and the row that has changed? This works also:

   `Dim checkbox As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender,CheckBox)`

To get the Row you only have to cast the NamingContainer of your Checkbox to GridViewRow.

`Dim row as GridViewRow =DirectCast(checkbox.NamingContainer,GridViewRow)`

**EDIT**: Do you rebind the ElegibilitySelectedGridview-Grid on Postback?
You should only do that when `not Page.IsPostback`, otherwise events won't fire.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your help but I have assigned the (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) to the working event just to keep consistency, but it hasnt changed anything. Also as far as iterating through the views, I can look into that once I get the event to at least fire, I want to focus in getting that fixed first.

Comment: You baffle me. Your working handler actually has the wrong signature: `Public Sub AssignElegibility()`. This should result in a runtime error 'does not have a signature compatible with delegate Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.

Comment: Okay Tim, but even without the signature it IS working. I also have taken your suggestion and added the corresponding signature as you suggested. However, still no results. So the signature issue goes away now because it is now there. Any idea of why the event is not being fired?

Comment: I mentionded that because this weird behaviour is noticeable and may indicate that something is substantial wrong or at least not mentioned by you.
Btw, i have updated my answer.

Comment: Tim, thank you for sticking with me here. You fixed the problem for me, I was rewiring the GridView onpage_load with no conditionals around it. Thank you much for your help!